# Complex numbers in sympy

Tags: sympy

I am using lcapy together with sympy and trying to process complex numbers from a circuit.

I have the following sympy expression:

```
import sympy
from lcapy import j

expr = sympy.parse_expr('L*w_0*(C*R*w_0 - I)')
expr
```

Output:

```
L⋅w₀⋅(C⋅R⋅w₀ - ⅉ)
```

`expr` above is an complex expression with `ⅉ` being the imaginary number. Can I use sympy and remove the brackets from `expr` in order to view it in the more canonical form for complex numbers as

```
w₀^2⋅R⋅L⋅C - ⅉ⋅w₀⋅L
```

And does sympy have support for handling complex numbers? I want to get the argument of `expr` which should be:

```
arctan(L⋅w₀ / w₀^2⋅R⋅L⋅C)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can do (in an `isympy` session):

```
In [13]: expr
Out[13]: L⋅w₀⋅(C⋅R⋅w₀ - ⅈ)

In [14]: expr.expand()
Out[14]: 
        2         
C⋅L⋅R⋅w₀  - ⅈ⋅L⋅w₀
```

### edit

try

```
atan2(im(expr), re(expr))
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html

Refining the variables:

```
In [53]: C,L,R,w_0=symbols('C L R w_0',real=True, positive=True)    
In [54]: expr=L*w_0*(C*R*w_0-I)

In [55]: expr
Out[55]: L⋅w₀⋅(C⋅R⋅w₀ - ⅈ)

In [56]: expr.expand()
Out[56]: 
        2         
C⋅L⋅R⋅w₀  - ⅈ⋅L⋅w₀

In [57]: im(_),re(_)
Out[57]: 
⎛               2⎞
⎝-L⋅w₀, C⋅L⋅R⋅w₀ ⎠
```

Now the `atan2` is simplified:

```
In [59]: atan2(*_)
Out[59]: 
     ⎛  1   ⎞
-atan⎜──────⎟
     ⎝C⋅R⋅w₀⎠
```

And `arg` does the same:

```
In [60]: arg(_56)
Out[60]: arg(C⋅R⋅w₀ - ⅈ)

In [62]: arg(expr)
Out[62]: arg(C⋅R⋅w₀ - ⅈ)

In [77]: arg(expr)._eval_rewrite_as_atan2(expr)
Out[77]: 
     ⎛  1   ⎞
-atan⎜──────⎟
     ⎝C⋅R⋅w₀⎠
```

Comment: Thanks, ```expand``` works nicely. The symbols in sympy seem to be complex by default, so by doing ```Symbol("R", real=True)``` for each symbol ```R```, ```L```, ```C```, ```w_0```, the ```im(expr)``` and ```re(expr)``` functions work. I thought i could use [arg](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#arg) on ```expr```, but it does not seem to give my expected output.

Comment: I got a little further by specifying both real and positive.